# Find basis for $N(T)$ where $T: P_2(\mathbb R) \to P_3(\mathbb R)$ defined by $(Tf)(t)= tf(t) + f'(t)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Can someone please walk me through the procedure and show me an example where $N(T) \neq 0$.
I started with arbitrary polynomial, e.g $a + bt + ct^2$. I applied the transformation, set it equal to $0$ and got $(a + 2c)t + bt^2 + ct^3 + b = 0$. Where do I go from here. I'm told $N(T) = {0}$ but no steps are shown.
I know how to find the basis for $R(T)$ but basis of nullspaces for poly. give me trouble. Thank you for your time.

Comment: As stated, $Tf$ should be a polynomial of degree at most two. Do you mean $(Tf)(t) = tf(t) + f'(t)$?

Comment: Now you can set each of the coefficients of the polynomial equal to 0, which gives $b=0, a+2c=0, $ and $c=0$.  Therefore $a=b=c=0$, so $a+bt+ct^2$ is the zero polynomial.

Comment: can you give me an example of when the coefficients would not be zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wish to find a basis for the nullspace of the linear map
\begin{array}{ccc}
P_2(\Bbb R) & \xrightarrow{T} & P_3(\Bbb R) \\
f(t)        & \mapsto     & tf(t)+f^\prime(t)
\end{array}
Let $e_i(t)=t^i$ for $0\leq i\leq 3$. Note that 
\begin{align*}
\alpha &=\{e_0,e_1,e_2\} \\
\beta  &=\{e_0,e_1,e_2,e_3\}
\end{align*}
are bases for $P_2(\Bbb R)$ and $P_3(\Bbb R)$ respectively. The computations
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
T(e_0) & = & e_1 & = & \color{red}{0}\,e_0 & + & \color{green}{1}\,e_1 &+& \color{blue}{0}\,e_2 &+& \color{purple}{0}\,e_3 \\
T(e_1) & = & e_0+e_2 &=& \color{red}{1}\,e_0 &+& \color{green}{0}\,e_1 &+&\color{blue}{1}\,e_2&+&\color{purple}{0}\,e_3 \\
T(e_2) &=& 2\,e_2+e_3 &=& \color{red}{0}\,e_0 &+& \color{green}{0}\,e_1&+&\color{blue}{2}\,e_2&+&\color{purple}{1}\,e_3
\end{array}
imply that the matrix of $T$ relative to the bases $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is
$$
[T]_\alpha^\beta=
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}0&\color{red}1&\color{red}0\\
\color{green}1&\color{green}0&\color{green}0 \\
\color{blue}0&\color{blue}1&\color{blue}2\\ \color{purple}0&\color{purple}0&\color{purple}1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
But $\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}\rank[T]_\alpha^\beta=3$ (why?) and the Rank-Nullity Theorem says that if $A$ is $m\times n$, then
$$
\rank(A)+\dim\DeclareMathOperator{Null}{Null}\Null(A)=n
$$
In our case, we have
$$
3+\dim\Null[T]_\alpha^\beta=3
$$
so that $\dim\Null[T]_\alpha^\beta=0$. This implies that the equation $T(f)=0$ has no nontrivial solutions.

Answer (score 3):

$$0 = T(at^2 + bt + c) = t(at^2 + bt + c)+(2at+b)=at^3+bt^2 +(2a+c)t+b  $$
which implies $$a= b = c = 0.$$  that is the null space is trivial and has only the zero function.

this is to be expected as $$tf + f'= 0  $$ has the solution $$f = e^{-t^2/2}$$ which cannot be equal to a quadratic.

Comment: can you please show me an example where the coefficients are not all 0.

Comment: @curiousmind1995, the null space of $T$ has no nonzero polynomial, let alone a quadratic. as i explained in my response, if you make your domain differentiable functions, then the basis of the null space is spanned by $e^{-t^2/2}.$